# Php script to search a record from database by name. (filter by name)

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone correct the code for filter a record by its name. I know the query but perhaps I'm not implementing it properly.

Here is my code. I want to either search by city or simply put a name in textbox to search an hospital. search-by-name is for an input field where I am supposed to write the name I want to search from database. I want to make both options available. How should I implement it correctly, as this one won't work for me.

```php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['search-by-city'])) {
        $city_id = $_POST['search-by-city'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE `City_ID` LIKE '$city_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if (isset($_POST['search-by-name'])) {
            $hospital_name = $_POST['search-by-name'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE `Name` LIKE '$hospital_name'";
            $result = filterTable($query); {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    echo '<div class="col-md-12"> <h2>No recod Found</h2> </div> ';
                }
            }
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $city_id = $row[3];
            $query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `cites` WHERE `ID` LIKE '$city_id'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
            $city_name = $row2[0];
            echo '<div class="col-md-4"><h3>'.$row[1].'</h3><h4>'.$city_name.'</h4><h4>'.$row[2].'</h4><h5>'.$row[3].'</h5><h5>'.$row[4].'</h5>
';
}
}
```

Comment: The code is unreadable and you haven't actually described what the problem is.  It's unlikely anybody will be able to help.

Comment: I want to search and display names of hospitals by entering the name of hospital. (Just like we search a friend on facebook by his name)

Comment: You are entirely misunderstanding what Stack Overflow does.  Please take a look at the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Here is the scenario.
I have two options to get names of hospitals (stored in a database).
1st option is to search hospitals by selecting city from a list. (Which is working fine). 2nd option is that I write the name in a text box, and press search, and name i searched will be displayed. (Which I'm facing problems with).

Comment: So far the only problem you've described is that you want someone to write your program for you.  Nobody here is going to do that.  Hire a programmer.

Comment: Sorry for my poor programming skills but I posted a code I wrote in the snippet. 1st part works fine but the 2nd one isn't working. That's where I need someone to please correct it for me.

Comment: This isn't a question of poor programming skills.  This is a question of poor reason and communication skills.  If you want someone to help with your problem, the very least you can do is *make the code readable* and *describe the problem*.  Consider this... If solving your problem isn't even worth your own time or effort, why should it be worth anybody else's?

Comment: I'll post again with a better code. Thanks anyway for your time sir.

Comment: I tried to clean up your code snippet, but it was _very_ hard to understand. The easiest way to share code on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This will indent your code by an additional four spaces, which tells Stack Overflow to treat it as code.

Comment: Appreciated Sir. :) It was my first ever question on SO and pasted in hurry so couldn't check it properly. I have posted thequestion again. Hope this time my code makes a little sense.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052351/php-script-to-filter-by-name-the-results-from-database

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your query should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$hospital_name%'
```

Checkout the [mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) on string comparison.

Also please don't use $_POST variables directly in SQL queries, that is a major security issue. (Search for sql-injection.)

Comment: I have posted the question again, as the previous one was not indented prooperly and was much difficult to understand. Kindly take a look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052351/php-script-to-filter-by-name-the-results-from-database