# Php script to filter by name the results from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display hospital names from database by two ways:

1. By Selecting city.
2. By entering the name of hospital in search bar.

I wrote below php script. The 1st part works fine and shows all hospitals from a selected city, but 2nd part doesn't work for me. There is no error displayed. Need help with this. Did i not put the 'if' conditions in the right place? Or I missed something else?

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['search-by-city'])) {
        $city_id = $_POST['search-by-city'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE `City_ID` LIKE '%$city_id%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                echo '<h2>No recod Found</h2>' ;
            }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['search-by-name'])) {
            $hospital_name = $_POST['search-by-name'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$hospital_name%'";
            $result = filterTable($query); {

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                echo '<h2>No recod Found</h2>' ;
            }
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $city_id = $row[3];
        $query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `cities` WHERE `ID` LIKE '$city_id'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
        $city_name = $row2[0];

        echo '
            <h3>'.$row[1].'</h3>
            <h4>'.$city_name.'</h4> 
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: have you post your complete source code, because i am seeing an syntax error at this line. What are you doing here :
    
    $result = filterTable($query); {

Comment: this is for storing query result into $result variable. Query that i put to search by name. I guess this is the part where i'm making a mistake.